# Server Error TypeError: (0 , next_connect__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default) is not a function

Tags: node.js, next.js, next-connect

I've got this error while using **next-connect** package.(i'm following a guy on youtube)

[image]

here's my code

```
import nc from 'next-connect';
import Product from '../../../models/Product';
import db from '../../../utils/db';

const handler = nc();

handler.get(async (req, res) => {
  await db.connect();
  const products = await Product.find({});
  await db.disconnect();
  res.send(products);
});

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`next-connect` [v1.0.0](https://github.com/hoangvvo/next-connect/releases/tag/v1.0.0-next.0) was recently released and is not backward-compatible. You can either downgrade to a previous version (`npm install next-connect@0.12.1`), or change your current syntax to match the v1.0.0 version.

```js
import { createRouter } from 'next-connect';
import Product from '../../../models/Product';
import db from '../../../utils/db';

const router = createRouter();

router.get(async (req, res) => {
    await db.connect();
    const products = await Product.find({});
    await db.disconnect();
    res.send(products);
});

export default router.handler();
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution was very hard to find, so grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Change below value

import {createRouter} from 'next-connect';

const router = createRouter();

export default router.handler();