# 'next-connect' error (nextConnect is undefined)

Tags: javascript, next.js, middleware, next-connect

I am trying to integrate 'next-connect' into my Nextjs app in order to use multer inside of my middleware. I cannot import multer using the Nextjs built-in middleware feature (the one where you create a separate 'middleware.js' file). However, when I try to follow the documentation by importing 'next-connect' with `import nextConnect from 'next-connect';`, it says that nextConnect is undefined. 'next-connect' version is '1.0.0-next.2' and 'next' is the latest version. Inside 'pages/api/test.js':

```
import nextConnect from 'next-connect';

const apiRoute = nextConnect().post(req, res) => {
   res.status(200).json({ data: 'success' });
});
```

Comment: `next-connect` v1.0.0 uses a different API which is not backward-compatible. See [Server Error TypeError: (0 , next_connect__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default) is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72912514/server-error-typeerror-0-next-connect-webpack-imported-module-0-default).